# Is it possible put a maven log configuration into pom.xml instead command line arguments?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am trying put a `timestamp` into maven output logs. I know that if 
I update the **`$M2_HOME/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`** updating the parameters **`org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime`** and **`org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat`** I achieve what I need! Or I can pass **-D** and this properties into a mvn command line works too!

But I don't want let this configuration into a maven config property and neither have to pass this command into command line! My real need is put this `timestamp` into a specific profile, like integration test profile.

I have already put this configuration into a specific profile and I have tried too into project configuration (global configuration) and maven does not get this config/changing.

If I can log the time even out of a specific profile, it would already meet what I need. But inside into a profile will be better.

I have tried too change some properties into plugins too (using argLines, property/value, etc...) but no one worked!

I don't know if Maven is reading **`simplelogger.properties`** first and after this, it read the pom properties, doesn't replacing what maven has already read!

Comment: Simple answer to this. No it is not...The question is what kind of problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need that into a profile?

Comment: The main goal is: I just need to put timestamp in maven logs, but without the need to put in a property file or pass by command. Currently I am passing in command line, for example **mvn verify -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true**. In this way I will impact every mvn command, when I just need the timestamp logs in a integration test, that I have a specific profile. If it is possible put in this profile only, I believe that will be better! Otherwise, I will let into command line, affecting all maven profile (unit test, integration test, etc).

Comment: Complementing, I have a shell script that call the command mvn in a automatized process! I don't want affect all process, just my project or my profile.

Comment: You are writing about integration tests? Do I understand your explanation right that you need that only for your integration tests?

Comment: Right! I need just for my integration tests.

Comment: The question is: Could make the configuration only for the integration tests in the appropriate src/test/resources directory instead on Maven level?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But, how I can would do in this way?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to have timestamps show up in my logs on the build server. Changing any configuration on the build server requires a time consuming change request. Changing the pom requires pushing a button. Also, I would like timestamps automatically even on a new developers machine, so if something is being slow we have an immediate idea of what and how slow, rather than having to explain that they need to set up some properties somewhere, etc., etc. And I would like to have it automatic on my machine, even when I get a new computer, so I don't have to remember to set this.